# Ubuntu 23.04 System can't recover . Problem has occurred. Deadscreen

Tags: 23.04

I am using Ubuntu 23.04 x84_64. I am getting this screen. Saying to login again, but loging in is not doing anything.

In previous session, I installed fuse and libfuse2
`sudo apt install fuse libfuse2`  and I was trying to install pyqt5 , but cancelled it because of slow internet connection.
[image]

[image]

I have no idea why it is happening. Please help me .

Comment: Google `Ubuntu recovery mode` - to find instructions how to enter there... then you will probably need to either attempt re-install or maybe remove (and clean up after) all remnants of QT and pyqt - to begin with.